# Vscode move line above a block shortcut key

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there any shortcut key to move a line above or below a block? This feature exists in IntelliJ editors and maybe also in visual studio.

You can use <kbd>Alt+Up</kbd> to move a line up one line. Is there any such shortcut key to move the line above an entire block above?

In the example below, it's to move the line `a = 1;` above the `if` block

[image: description]

Comment: Would selecting the if block and (Alt+Down)ing it solve your issue or are you looking for a more general solution?

Comment: @FilipKaštovský Yeah but that will not work for passing multiple blocks. I was looking if there is a direct move through blocks shortcut key just like in other editors like IntelliJ and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single command for moving current line above/below adjacent block (at this moment), but you can get pretty close by selecting and moving the block instead. `Expand selection` (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RightArrow</kbd>) and "normal" `Move line up/down` (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up/Down</kbd>) will come handy here:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try using <kbd>Alt+Up</kbd>, that works for me.

It's also on the context menu if you need it ...

[image: Context]

You can also select blocks of code and use the same shortcut to move the entire lot.  This would work in your case.

Comment: That only moves one line up. And for big blocks, you will have to go through all the lines pressing `alt+up`

Comment: @Abraham This does also work with blocks of code. You have to simple roughly select the lines of code you want to move and then press alt+up

Comment: Sorry, should've read your question properly but I also reacted to your original write up that included **Shift** in the shortcut you were referencing.  I see you corrected your question.

Comment: yeah, shift was to duplicate the line. It's a typo sorry

Comment: I'll update the answer to include the block selection.  It may help someone else.  @josias for the win.